# SyndicationItem Content encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rss, syndication-item

I am adding some simple tags to my SyndicationItem Content object like

```
var newSyndicationItem = new SyndicationItem(item.Title, item.Brief, new Uri("http://www.x.com/news/" + item.ID));
newSyndicationItem.PublishDate = new DateTimeOffset(item.PublishDate.Value);
newSyndicationItem.Content = SyndicationContent.CreateHtmlContent("<p style='direction:rtl' align='right' ><img src='http://x.sa.net/news/small/" + item.PicName + "' align='right' />" + item.Brief + "</p>");
```

and rss output encodes the html tags, how can I fix this issue

```
<item>
      <link>http://www.x.com/news/details/3851</link>
      <title></title>
      <description>&lt;p style='direction:rtl' align='right' &gt;&lt;img src='http://x.sa.net/news/small/587_660.jpg' align='right' /&gt;قال أحمد خيري المتحدث الرسمي باسم حزب المصريين الأحرار في تصريح خاص لـ "الوطن"، أن سبب إصدار بيان الحزب اليوم، الذي يندد بالدعاية الدينية في المساجد&lt;/p&gt;</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 14 May 2012 17:16:04 +0200</pubDate>
    </item>
```

please advice.

Comment: Could you please put some code? I have build RSS by deriving from ActionResult and  and building the RSS with XMLWriter and it worked. How are you doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to be fixed. That's valid XML and every decent XML parser will be able to read it correctly. If you do not properly encode the value of the description tag you will probably end up with invalid RSS.